# Hide child view if parent view's height is less than a certain limit

Tags: android, layout, android-webview

I have few text elements and under that there is a webView.
I don't want the view to be scrollable.
So if the height of the device is very small (ex. 3.5 inch screens) I don't want to display the webView and only display the text elements.

Is there any way to hide the webView if it cannot be displayed fully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control Visibility of any View by

```
webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

You can also use

```
webView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Just try to use those functions under some condition. Check size of parent view and if it's lower than some value, make webView INVISIBLE. 
The difference between **INVISIBLE** and **GONE** is that first one works similar to making it completely transparent (but it still uses space in layout) while the second one deletes the View from layout.

```
if(((CAST_HERE)webView.getParent()).getHeight() < minHeight)
    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by CAST_HERE? Is it some variable?

Comment: CAST_HERE is the type of parent container, for example LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.

Comment: can the same be achieved via using a different layout folder?

Comment: Yes you can customize your layout by putting files in different folders. Have a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score -1):

Use resource manager for this. Really learn to leverage it, as it is essential for this multi-resolution problem

So ... find out what density bucket would that be (mdpi, hdpi.. ), and just provide different layout with the same name

Comment: can you please provide code which can be used for the layout? I don't think that android has a layout-sh for using a layout which checks the height. Their documentation thinks only about the width since according to them scrolling can be used for variable height.

Comment: well, you can try the "available height", even tho I personally havent used it yet http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

but my bet would be lets say mdpi, because then you ran into the screen size / screen resolution mess, .. there are plenty of qualifiers 

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html